# Not Able To Add A New User To An Existing Account Using Management API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to add a new user to our google analytics account using the Management API, using the Javascript code on the google website. 
I get an error response message stating "Your project does not have access to this feature." How can I rectify this ?

Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Web property Guide has the details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtWebpropertyGuide), but basically:

- Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) is currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're interested in using these features, [request access to the beta](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1xyjp6ca4YkGjh7TDi1Z3XyA3XHcRHkKzFentxzUrmPY/viewform).